# Set a tuple of strings as a dict key

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to create a dictionary where the keys are a tuple of strings and the values are integers. I have done it using the CSV module but with pandas, I can better manage my data.

Basically I want this:

```
print(Supply)
{(1, 1): 400, (1, 2): 0, (2, 1): 1500, (2, 2): 0, (3, 1): 900, (3, 2): 0}
```

To become this:

```
print(Supply)
{('1', '1'): 400, ('1', '2'): 0, ('2', '1'): 1500, ('2', '2'): 0, ('3', '1'): 900, ('3', '2'): 0}
```

Comment: Why do you want the integers as strings? You'll just have to convert them to integers again if you want to use them for anything

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: @quamrana The code that I used is in Jethro`s answer, I just copied and pasted it. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @mousetail I am building an optimization model using a variable with multiple indexes, since I am in an early stage I`m using some fake data. These indexes will be regions code as well. Idk if I have answered what you asked, let me know if you need anything else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the transformation you want:

```py
Supply = {tuple(str(i) for i in key): val for key, val in Supply.items()}

print(Supply)

# {('1', '1'): 400, ('1', '2'): 0, ('2', '1'): 1500, ('2', '2'): 0, ('3', '1'): 900, ('3', '2'): 0}
```

Comment: Glad to hear! Mind marking the answer as accepted then?

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot! Done!